# Where is the log file created when debugging Azure Function in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a Timer Azure Function which I execute in VS. Right click on the Azure Function project and Debug. The function has an ILogger log.

Inspecting the log object I can see that is has two loggers

- Azure.Functions.Cli.Diagnostics.ColoredConsoleLogger
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.FileLogger

I also can see that the RootLogPath is %temp%\LogFiles\Application\Functions.

However at that location there is only a "Host" folder. I expected to find a "Function" folder as well with the log file.

Do I need to enable somehow the File Logger? Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get file logs in local dev, we do have to modify the `fileLoggingMode` to `always` in `host.json`. The default `debugOnly` setting doesn't make function write file logs locally.

For [v2 Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always"
  }
}
```

For [v1 Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#tracing)

```
{
    "tracing": {
      "fileLoggingMode": "always"
    }
}
```

Comment: Work also for me thank you! (voted). However, a bit concerned with the name "debugOnly" they chose. Maybe "azureOnly" or "productionOnly" would make more sense. When I am testing locally I am actually in "Debug" mode and the logger doesn't persist. It's misleading in my opinion, unless I missed something (very new to this topic)

Comment: Does "fileLoggingMode": "always" write logs to a file when debugging locally in VS, but it won't write to a file when published to Azure?